# including navigation property returning all records instead of just the property added

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

using EF Core code first approach i have my model setup like this

```
public class Author
{        
    public string Id{ get; set; }
    public string Name{ get; set; }
    public ICollection<Book> Books{ get; set; }
}
 public class Book
{        
    public string Id{ get; set; }
    public string Name{ get; set; }
    public Author Author{ get; set; }
}
```

when i have to add an Author its simple. but when i have to add a Book i have to tell which author it belongs to.

```
    DbSet = _context.Set<TEntity>();
    public async Task<TEntity> GetAsync(string id, string include = null)
    {
        var query = DbSet.Include(include);

        return await query.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == id);
    }
```

using a code like this i first get the Author

```
 public async Task<Book> AddBook(Book book, string authorId)
    {
        var author = await _authorRepo.GetAsync(authorId,  "Books");
        book.Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        author.Books.Add(book);
        _context.SaveChanges(); //(i have a reference to context here its a repository pattern)
        return book;
    }
```

So the problem is that when a book is returned a huge object is returned. a book that was added. and Author in that book and all the Books under that author. Any idea to return just the book that was added ?
any change in approach suggestion ?

Comment: Didn't get your question. Are you looking for this? `var book = await _context.Book
            .Where(x => x.Id== Id)
            .SingleOrDefaultAsync();`

Comment: using GetAsync i get the author for which i want to add a book. 
but sunce i am including books it fetch all the books of that author. and in that array i add the new book i want to add and call save change and return a book. but now this book is a huge object with a navigation property of Author and all of author books as well

Comment: Add `AuthorId` to `Book`: no need to set a `Book` property, the FK property is enough.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to create a separate `Book` repository where you could just work with books. This way you have more benefits like:

- Separate logic for each type: author, book, etc.
- Adding a book will not require you to retrieve the author first so less overload.
- In general it's a best practice to separate business logic between different types of entities.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JsonIgnoreAttribute` to exclude a property from serialization:

```
public class Book
{        
    public string Id{ get; set; }
    public string Name{ get; set; }
    
    [JsonIgnore]
    public Author Author{ get; set; }
}
```